# Acumatica Finding What Reports Use What Costing Method

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way in Acumatica to find what Report uses what costing method. (i.e. Historical Inventory Balance, Historical Inventory Valuation Report, Inventory Valuation Report)

I have found some information in the help articles about the costing methods used on items and created a GI displaying those methods; however, I have not found what report use what costing method.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `Report Parameter`, `DAC` and `Field` names used for the targeted business rules. Reports are stored as text file so you can easily search text inside them if you are self hosting the website (for SAAS use Download Website option).

Locate Acumatica instance virtual directory. It can be found using `Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard` under `Perform Application Maintenance->Instance Info->Instance Files Path`.

Using a text editor, search inside all report `*.rpx` files. Example below shows search result with `Notepad++` for the `FIFODefaultCost` keyword:
[image]